# Failed to find package metadata for jsonschema

Tags: python, metadata, jsonschema, python-importlib, python-jsonschema

I am fairly new to this. I installed `jsonschema` and `importlib_metadata` manually and copied it to the folder where I was doing `synthesis` using `make syn` i.e., `vlsi` folder in my case.

It terminates with this error: `importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for jsonschema`

```
[usr@serv vlsi]$ make syn
./example-vlsi -e /home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/env.yml  -p example.yml  -p /home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/build/chipyard.TestHarness.RocketConfig-ChipTop/inputs.yml --obj_dir /home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/build/chipyard.TestHarness.RocketConfig-ChipTop build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example-vlsi", line 4, in <module>
    import hammer_vlsi
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/hammer_vlsi/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .hammer_vlsi_impl import *
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/hammer_vlsi/hammer_vlsi_impl.py", line 22, in <module>
    from hammer_tech import Library, ExtraLibrary
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/hammer_tech.py", line 18, in <module>
    import python_jsonschema_objects  # type: ignore
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/python_jsonschema_objects/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    __version__ = metadata.version("jsonschema")
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 585, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 558, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/home/usr/chipyard/vlsi/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 215, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for jsonschema
make: *** No rule to make target 'syn'.  Stop.
```

I found some solutions to this here: http://biercoff.com/how-to-fix-package-not-found-error-importlib-metadata/ but where to find serverless.yml file and will making `slim` true to false affect other things?
Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: after installing plugin serverless-python-requirements  serverless.yml will appear
serverless plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
then in custom section add
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    slim: true

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the slim option.   Even disabling it didn't help.   However, this bug has a workaround that does.

```
pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    useDownloadCache: false
    useStaticCache: false
    slim: true
    slimPatternsAppendDefaults: false
    slimPatterns:
      - '**/*.py[c|o]'
      - '**/__pycache__*'
```

https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/584